# Install another app after user choose 'Install' in the UI but before start the services

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

I'm using Wix# to create windows MSI installer.

I want to to install a specific version of .NET MSI installer via my installer.

I want to do this only after the user clicks on 'Install' on the UI but before the installer start the services,

My installer also start a service by using `ServiceInstaller` and my service need the .NET SDK to be installed in order to start successfully.

Where should I locate the custom action that install the .NET SDK?

Im using custom action to install the .NET SDK by creating a process and run the msi in a silent mode

Thx

Comment: Is a bootstrapper is an option for you? Or is the `msi` output mandatory?

Comment: @Serg I do prefer not to use a bootstrapper it will require a refactoring because my installer is type of custom ui. i can run a custom action that run a cmd that install the msi silently.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524982/how-can-i-execute-a-custom-action-in-wix-just-before-service-installation. You can also try the `StartServices` step instead of `InstallServices`. However, I have not tried this myself.